# Does "none" take cause SV-inversion?

Tags: usage, word-usage

Consider the following:

- From none of the documents can it be taken that cats like mice.
- From none of the documents it can be taken that cats like mice.

To me, the second Option sounds correct.

However, with

- In None of the books are cats mentioned.
- In None of the books cats are mentioned.

the second, non-inverted Option seems to be correct.

Can anyone solve the mystery?

Comment: "However" implies a difference between the first and the second part of your question, but they are the same (in both cases no inversion). _None_ has nothing to do with your question, because you can replace the first part of your sentences with any other indication of a source, e.g. "In three glass jars", "On the entire internet", without changing the grammatical structure of what follows. You are basically asking whether or not inversion occurs when you start a sentence with a _prepositional phrase_. Maybe you'd like to reword your question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Good question, made me think :-)

In both cases the inverted subject-auxiliary forms sounded/looked better to my ear/eye, for the same reason that we use subject-verb inversion after "in no case", for example one could say: "In no case were cats mentioned in the documents."
According to [this explanation](http://englishniche.com/2013/02/26/inversions-inverted-subjects-and-verbs/), the subject and verb/auxiliary must be inverted when the:

> sentence or main clause begins with certain negative or almost
>   negative expressions

The explanation given doesn't explicitly mention the clauses beginning "from none" but it is easy to find examples online using a [google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22from%20none%20of%20these%20do%22).

In short, yes, clauses beginning "in none of" or "from none of" do require subject-verb inversion.